# Lie bracket of tangent vectors in a submanifold is tangent to the submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections, submanifold, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $N$ a submanifold of $M$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector field of $N$.

We know that the differentials on $M$ of those vector fields $d_XY$ and $d_YX$ are not necessarily tangent to $N$, and so we need to project them on to $TN$ to define a connection on $N$.

However, looking at the proof in my course that the projected connection is torsion free (for $M=\mathbb R^n$), it seems like the same is not true for the Lie bracket on $M$ defined by $[X,Y]=d_XY-d_YX$ which is tangent to $N$ without needing to be projected. Why is this true?

Comment: Hint: use coordinates adapted to the submanifold together with $$[fX,gY]=fg[X,Y]+fX(g)Y-gY(f)X.$$

Comment: @IvoTerek Sorry if this is very trivial, but since [X,Y] is not a tensorial object, I'm not sure how it would transform when changing the coordinate chart.

Comment: You don't need to know. Again: choose an adapted chart, write $X$ and $Y$ in coordinates, compute the Lie bracket using the above formula with $X$ and $Y$ there playing the role of coordinate fields and you will see that all the "transverse" coefficients of $[X,Y]$ vanish.

Comment: Well if I write things in coordinate I believe I have $[X,Y]=x^\mu(\partial_\mu y^\nu)\partial_\nu-y^\mu(\partial_\mu x^\nu)\partial_\nu$. 

And then if the chart is adapted, all the transverse coordinates are 0 on the submanifold, so if $\nu$ is a given transverse coordinate $\partial_\mu y^\nu$ is non zero only if $\mu$ is transverse too, but that implies its coefficient in the sum $x^\mu$ is 0. So all terms are 0.

But with such a method I would have shown that each side of the difference is 0 independently, isn't this an issue given $d_XY$ should not be tangent?

Comment: Yes. That's the argument.

Comment: @IvoTerek sorry I sent the comment before having finished it. Could you check that the end is coherent? 

Also thinking about it, is the reason that this proof doesn't work for a single $d_XY$ that for longitudinal $\mu$ and transverse $\nu$, $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu$ is non zero, only $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu - \partial_\nu \partial_\mu$ is 0? In my head the derivative was 0, but I suppose that intuition is just plain wrong.

Comment: $d_XY$ is not even a vector field. $[X,Y]$ is. The point is that the transverse components of $X$ and $Y$ being zero will force the ones for $[X,Y]$ to vanish as well by your formula. I'm sorry, I'm on mobile right now and can't stop to write a full detailed answer. You will have to think a bit harder on your own in case this doesn't fully clarify it. Good luck!